# Merge command causes 'missing keyword' error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsqldeveloper

I have problem with this query:

```
  MERGE INTO qot
  USING dual
  ON (qot_id = 1023125885)
  WHEN MATCHED AND qot_exc_id = 4 THEN UPDATE SET qot_exc_id = 259
  WHEN MATCHED AND qot_exc_id = 6 THEN UPDATE SET qot_exc_id = 131;
```

I'm getting an error: 'Missing keyword'.
Could someone give me any clue?

Thank you!

Greetings,

r.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why you are trying to use MERGE when you only want to update, never insert.  You cannot add conditions into the WHEN clause like you are doing - see [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9016.htm#i2081218).

Why not just do this:

```
update qot
set qot_exc_id = case qot_exc_id
                    when 4 then 259
                    when 6 then 131
                    end
where qot_id = 1023125885
and qot_exc_id in (4,6);
```

If you really need a MERGE then you want something like:

```
MERGE INTO qot
USING dual
ON (qot_id = 1023125885)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
  UPDATE SET qot_exc_id = case qot_exc_id
                            when 4 then 259
                            when 6 then 131
                            else qot_exc_id
                            end;
```

or perhaps:

```
MERGE INTO qot
USING dual
ON (qot_id = 1023125885 and qot_exc_id in (4,6))
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
  UPDATE SET qot_exc_id = case qot_exc_id
                            when 4 then 259
                            when 6 then 131
                            end;
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback! It was only an example. I wanna more complex statement.

Comment: I mean, that I wanna statement with inserts.

Comment: Thank you very much again... I have one more problem with the last merge...  Can I update only if the condition is passed?

Comment: hmm.. i need to match qot and check exc... if strictly speaking i need to check if it there is +/-x% aberrancy. if the threshold is kept, i need to update , if not, i don't want to update. and if the qot is not there i want to insert...